# How can i get Youtube Video Title at Searching Page

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I can get all video info at Youtube/watch?v=videolink but I want to get link and title from Youtube/results?search-query page.

```
webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/watch?v=VIDEOID"}
```

I got the video url with this regex `"/\/watch\?v=(.*?)[&\"]/i"`

```
Output:VIDEOID
```

but I cannot get the Title in

```
title":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"#VIDEOTITLE"
```

because there are so many labels in source. Is it possible to regex it all things from title to :" and output like `#VIDEOTITLE` ? Or other way to get it?

Comment: What you got there looks like JSON … if that’s the case, then properly _decode_ it into a PHP data structure, instead of messing around with regular expressions.

Comment: Why not just use their API?

Comment: Don't parse json with a regex as the json may contain optional whitespaces and still may remain valid but your regex may stop working unless you obsessively handle optional whitespaces using `\s*` which would make the regex ugly. Not sure what stops you to write a regex just like you already did for getting videoid. It is [simple](https://regex101.com/r/gKGa1X/1) but like I said, better go for a json parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to get search results from YouTube will be by the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword)

(from the YouTube Data API docs)
First get the results, and then you can get the title from each video

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
      'q' => $_GET['q'],
      'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
));

// Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
// matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {
        case 'youtube#video':
          $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['videoId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#channel':
          $channels .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['channelId']);
          break;
        case 'youtube#playlist':
          $playlists .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
              $searchResult['snippet']['title'], $searchResult['id']['playlistId']);
          break;
      }
    }
```